# Why can the learning rate make the loss increase in stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, learning-rate

In Deep Learning by Goodfellow et al., I came across the following line on the chapter on Stochastic Gradient Descent (pg. 287):

> The main question is how to set $\epsilon_0$. If it is too large, the
> learning curve will show violent oscillations, with the cost function
> often increasing significantly.

I'm slightly confused why the loss function would increase at all. My understanding of gradient descent is that given parameters $\theta$ and a loss function $\ell (\vec{\theta})$, the gradient update is performed as follows:

$$\vec{\theta}_{t+1} = \vec{\theta}_{t} - \epsilon \nabla_{\vec{\theta}}\ell (\vec{\theta})$$

The loss function is guaranteed to monotonically decrease because the parameters are updated in the negative direction of the gradient. I would assume the same holds for SGD, but clearly it doesn't. With a high learning rate $\epsilon$, how would the loss function increase in its value? Is my interpretation incorrect, or does SGD have different theoretical guarantees than vanilla gradient descent?

Answer (score 1):

This is the case as the loss doesn't have to monotonically decrease when it's updated in the negative direction.
For example:

Let $L(\theta) = \theta^2 $  and $\theta_0= 3$

Let the subscript n in $\theta_n$ denote the iteration number.

Then $\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_0) = 2*\theta = 2*3 = 6$

For the loss to decrease in this case $\epsilon < 1$ needs to hold so lets look at when it doesn't hold.

If $\epsilon = 1$ then the loss would be stable at 6 as the update would give $\theta_1 = \theta_0 - 1*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_0) = 3-6 = -3 $

$\theta_2 = \theta_1 - 1*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_1)  = -3 -- 6 = 3$

$\theta_3 = \theta_2 - 1*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_2) = 3 - 6 = -3$

$L(\theta_1) = L(\theta_2) =L(\theta_3) = 6$
As $L(-3) = (-3)^2 = 6$ and $L(3) = 3^2 = 6$

So if $\epsilon = 1$ then $\theta$ will oscillate back and forth between 3 and -3 what gives a loss that is stable at 6.

Now if we look at what happens if $\epsilon >1$ for example $\epsilon =2$

note that $\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta) = 2*\theta$ as $L(\theta) = \theta^2$

$\theta_1 = \theta_0 - 2*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_0) =  3 -2*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_0)  = 3 - 2 * (2*3) = 3 - 12 = -9$

$\theta_2 = \theta_1 - 2*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_1)  = -9 - 2 *\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_1) = -9-2*(2*-9) = -9 + 36 = 27$

$\theta_3 = \theta_2 - 2*\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_2)  = 27 - 2 *\nabla_{\theta}L(\theta_2) = 27 -2 * (2*27) = 27 -108 = -81 $

In  turn the loss would  increase after each update .

$L(\theta_1) = (-9)^2 = 81$

$L(\theta_2) = 27^2 = 729$

$(\theta_3) = (-81)^2 = 6561$

Comment: The explanations in this answer seem correct to me. However, the learning rate is usually a number in the range $(0, 1)$ (see [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23748/2444)), so maybe, in that excerpt, the authors were already assuming that the learning rate is not bigger or equal to 1. So, you may want to comment on that case too.

Comment: The cited text says when it's too large, so commonly used learning rates don't apply, but I get what you mean. The actual chosen value of epsilon fully depends on the behavior of the loss landscape.